# find links in mechanize python

Tags: python

I'm currently using mechanize to auto navigate some link from a website. The problem is mechanize cannot find all link in my website. When i use:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> web = mechanize.Browser()
>>> r = web.open('http://torrent.ajee.sh/hash.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963')
>>> print r.read()
```

it actually print out this:

```
Adulterers.2015.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO (1.38 GB)<br/>Files: <br/>O <a href='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=0' target='_top' >Adulterers.2015.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi </a> (1.4 GB) -- (<font color=''>100% </font> Cached)<br/>O <a href='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=1' target='_top' >Adulterers.2015.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.nfo </a> (2 KB) -- (<font color=''>100% </font> Cached)<br/>O <a href='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=3' target='_top' >sample.avi </a> (16.1 MB) -- (<font color=''>100% </font> Cached)<br/>O <a href='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=2' target='_top' >Torrent Downloaded From ExtraTorrent.cc.txt </a> (338 B ) -- (<font color=''>100% </font> Cached)<br/><br/><br/><a href='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=zip' target='_top'>Download Zip</a> (1.38 GB)<br/><br/> If Download links not working, then Try again after few mints, <b>Files are been Cached(100%)</b>.<br/><br/>
```

and there are totally 5 links in it!

but when i use:

```
print list(web.links())
```

it just contains the first link in that source! what is the problem?

```
[Link(base_url='http://torrent.ajee.sh/hash.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963', url='/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=0', text='Adulterers.2015.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO.avi', tag='a', attrs=[('href', '/file.php?hash=ee59bf932540976857c38eee56e2a598154a9963&file=0'), ('target', '_top')])]
```

sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the links:

```
for link in web.links():
    print(link.text, link.url)
```

links() is a generator and gives you the next link each time you ask for another link.

Comment: Well sorry mate, this looks like a problem with the website. The code itself does what it should on other websites. You may want to look at [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for such cases